# Twitter "Tweet" button not working on live site

Tags: button, twitter, tweets

Published this website but the Tweet button doesn't appear to be working. I can share with Facebook but the Tweeter "Tweet" button is INOP.

Anybody has any idea what's wrong with that button? that I know I have included all there is to include.

site page is http://www.PanamaVibes.com/Provinces/

Many others have the twitter button but they all use the same master page so the problem exists in all the pages that have the social thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<header>` element for the title on the left is a block element, and it is is going over the floated `<aside>` element that contains the buttons. Setting that `<header>` element to `display: inline-block;` will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a million! your solution also gave me another idea that works just as well: add z-index:100; position:relative; to the <aside>element that contains the buttons. The z-works on relative positioning and with that high value it comes above the header as well.